# Do not use all MATLAB pool workers

Tags: multithreading, matlab, matlabpool

I have set up a local Matlab (R2015b) pool of workers according to my CPU configuration (quad-core, multi-threading => 8 workers in total.)

I have simulations that last 24h but I want to be able to use my computer at the same time. Therefore, I limit myself to 4 simulations a day (sent via batch) so that I can keep working at the same time.

My question is this: *how can I queue several jobs without eating up the 8 workers?* Another related question is *if I reduce the size of the pool to 4 workers, will I still be able to run Matlab smoothly?*

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Don't create 8 workers. Create 4. Will you be able to run MATLAB smoothly? probably not. You are asking to those 4 workers A LOT. They will try to take as much computing power as they can.

Comment: I compared the estimation time with 4 and 8 workers. Having 8 workers does not reduce computation speed as compared to 4 workers. I concluded that this was an efficient way to speed up what I had to do. One of the workarounds that I found is to use pause() when submitting jobs such that it is exactly 24h between each round of 4 simulations, but that does not satisfy me. Why do you say that I should not create 8 workers ?

Comment: Wait, you use **double** the processors and the speed doesnt get reduced? then your code is wrong. I say, if you want to use the PC, dont create 8. Do create 8 if you can have the PC idle computing.

Comment: EDIT: anecdotal evidence suggests that running it on only 4 cores would last 20 hours instead of 24 hours. The results are not really comparable as the speed of the CPU varies across the two sets. At any rate, multi-threading is still faster than single-core computations. Thank you.

Comment: Don't get offended if I say its wrong! Honestly, if 4-8 cores gives you so little inprovement, it could be due to the structure of the code, and you may be able to speed up that significantly. Consider profiling your code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri What you suggests should of course be tested, you should however remember that matlab have a lot of codes that internally is already multithreaded. So if user89073 code have a lot of those it won't help to further parallelize it.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Yes indeed. But that's exactly the point. Dont use lots of cores and a parpool if the speedup is small!

Comment: I did not get offended. I have learned to know better ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the best solution to your problem is to do it via bash in stead of matlab. In bash you have a command called [nice](http://ss64.com/bash/nice.html) which allows you to down prioritize the simulation. Which means that if you are using the computer you will get the power, and if you are not using it, the power goes to the computations.

Regarding the second part of your question. The easiest way to queue all the jobs is to make a bash script something like the following:

```
for f in $(find . -name name_of_matlab_script*)
do
nice -n 10 matlab -nodisplay <$f
done
```

where the name of the matlab scripts would be called something with the same base and then the start will take care of the rest. Then it will run the scripts after each other however give priority to what you otherwise use your computer for.

If you want more advanced scheduling software I normally uses [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com).

Regarding the 4 workers in stead of 8, then as Ander Biguri says in the comments, as few as possible as long as you do not add to much extra time.